# Bootstrap 4 Center Pagination in Column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and attempting to horizontally center a `pagination` UL inside a grid column. Now that the `pagination` is `display:flex` I can't get it to properly center.

I would like to **use *only* existing Bootstrap classes** w/o any additional CSS to get it centered.

I have tried using `text-center`, `mx-auto`, `align-items-center` but nothing seems to work.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 py-5 border">
            <ul class="pagination mx-auto">
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">«</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">»</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [Code example](http://www.codeply.com/go/TGWKYqHPFL)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I changed the column to display:flex using `d-flex` and now `mx-auto` works to center the pagination UL...

**This works without extra CSS**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 py-5 border d-flex">
            <ul class="pagination mx-auto">
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">«</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">»</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/JQKwUW2Tjg

Alternately, the `justify-content-center` class can be used in the 'pagination` UL.

Answer (score 60):

Just add `justify-content: center;` in `.pagination` class

```
.pagination {
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Here is working code: https://jsfiddle.net/r9z25u06/

Comment: Welcome.. if answer was helping you then please accept the answer.. thanks :)

Comment: Or just use the class `.justify-content-center` on the `.pagination` `ul`.

Comment: for those using compiled SASS bootstrap4 I literally just added the above code into my custom.scss to fix the problem and then recompiled

Answer (score 23):

Use the class `.justify-content-center` on the `.pagination` `ul`.

e.g. `<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">`

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why classes such as `text-center` don't work here. Also, is there no `justify-content-right` or `justify-content-left`?

Comment: `justify-content-start` and `justify-content-end`.

Answer (score 6):

solution for **Bootstrap 4**

You can use it **Alignment** use this class `justify-content-center`

Change the alignment of pagination components with [flexbox utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/).

and learn more about it [pagination](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    <li class="page-item disabled">
      <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```