# Django: Pagination wont centre on page 1

Tags: python, html, css, django, pagination

I have added in a template pagination I found and it works fine but wont centre on page 1 even with "text-centre" and "justify-content-center" as recommended by other answers. It looks fine on page 2 and 3... as can be seen below

[image]

```
{% block pagination %}

            {% if is_paginated %}
        <div class="text-center">
            <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
              {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
              {% else %}
                <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
              {% endif %}
              {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
                {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                  <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
                {% else %}
                  <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
              {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
              {% else %}
                <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
              {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        
          {% endif %}

        {% endblock %}
```

This is the code i used and this is what it looks like on page 1 and its pulling to the right. I currently don't have any CSS code for the pagination, though I have tried different options with no luck.

[image]

If I remove the "text-centre" then page 1 is centred but pages 2/3 pull to the left, so I am a bit stumped.

p.s this is my first django post so please let me know if it needs more information etc.

Thank you!

edit: Added this to CSS but didn't work -

```
.pagination {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

tried d-flex class from a different answer, page 1 centred pages 2/3 pull left:

```
                {% block pagination %}

            {% if is_paginated %}
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 py-5 border d-flex">
                        <ul class="pagination mx-auto">
                            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                                <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
                            {% else %}
                                <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
                                {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                                <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
                                {% else %}
                                <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                                <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
                            {% else %}
                                <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try with this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43679608/6490744

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat i tried this one both adding it to the ul as seen above and in the CSS code!

Comment: did you try d-flex class also ?

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat see edits, tried the code from the answer but pages 2/3 pull to the right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out, in case anyone has the same issue, i needed to use similar layout classes to those i had on the rest of the page (silly me), such as "container-wrap" and "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center":

```
                {% block pagination %}

            {% if is_paginated %}
            <div class="container-wrap">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
                        <ul class="pagination mx-auto">
                            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                                <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
                            {% else %}
                                <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
                                {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                                <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
                                {% else %}
                                <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                                <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
                            {% else %}
                                <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
          {% endif %}

        {% endblock %}
```